# Клик по общему элементу jquery

Tags: jquery

Хочу сделать на сайте, что бы можно было скачать файл только когда нажали по рекламе.
Есть например реклама от гугла. Известно что он подгружает iframe.
Как узнать нажал ли пользователь на рекламу или нет?
Делаю так, но не получается, реклама на месте остаётся.

```
$(".reklama").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".block").css("display", "none");
})
```

Comment: Если `<iframe>` находится в другом домене, то вы не можете получить доступ к его содержимому.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iframeTracker: github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery

Comment: К сожалению не работает ваш вариант, потому что гугл реклама работает через iframe, а ссылка рекламная именно в этом ifram-e.

Comment: $(".reklama") - это что вы селектите?

Comment: <div class="reklama">
        <div class="download">
            Скачать файл
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            тут скрипт с рекламой от гугла
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: iframeTracker: https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery

Comment: Плагин помог, спасибо.
Разместите эту ссылку в главный ваш ответ и я сделаю вопрос решённым.

Comment: переделал коммент